# Access element in struct from another struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct that I use for database operations. It contains a char *table_field and an address to a char pointer in another struct (char **struct_addr)

```
struct {
char *table_field,
    **struct_addr;
} retr_sett[5] = {
   { .table_field = "ifconfig_ipaddr",  .struct_addr = &(ip_sett.ip_addr) },
   { .table_field = "ifconfig_netmask", .struct_addr = &(ip_sett.netmask) },
   { .table_field = "ifconfig_router",  .struct_addr = &(ip_sett.router) },
   { .table_field = "ifconfig_dns1",    .struct_addr = &(ip_sett.dns1) },
   { .table_field = "ifconfig_dns2",    .struct_addr = &(ip_sett.dns2) }
};
```

Later, I would like to access the "foreign struct" as follows:

```
*(retr_sett[0].struct_addr) = ipaddr_from_db;
```

But this code doesn't work for me. I hoped that I could access the char* within the struct ip_sett like this, but it seems to me that the value is written to the struct retr_sett.

Comment: Could you show the structure and its data member definition you are trying to access to?

Comment: @Igor that is not legal C syntax

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, my abovestanding code works. I just had an if-Clause that evaluated to false, and therefore the struct wasn't filled.